# Google search web scraping with a list of key words in python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to do web scraping on Google search by using a list of names as inputs and get dataset in a DataFame. I used selenium for web scraping before, I am having a difficult time building syntax **using loops to run a list of names as an input** to get the results and **scrape** each page. Here is my Python code below:

```
baseUrl = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
pluseUrl = input('CEO: ')    
url = baseUrl + quote_plus(pluseUrl)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get(url)

table = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.ifM9O') 

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ceo', 'value'])
values =[]


for row in table:
    ceo = str(([c.text for c in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.kno-ecr-pt.PZPZlf.gsmt.i8lZMc')])).strip('[]').strip("''")
    value = str(([c.text for c in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.Z1hOCe')])).strip('[]').strip("''")

ceo = pd.Series(ceo)
value = pd.Series(value)

df = df.assign(**{'ceo': ceo, 'value': value}) 


print(df)
```

And here is the result after putting Bill Gates as an input:

```
CEO: Bill gates
          ceo                                              value
0  Bill Gates  Born: October 28, 1955 (age 64 years), Seattle...
```

Any suggestions or recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the quote_plus part for? also what exactly do you want in the "value" column

Comment: @Gorlomi the quote_plus part was created to input the name manually. I want to change and move it into a loop. for the output of this code, I want to have a dataframe consists of two columns - CEO, and value - including list of CEOs. The value part, in the example I showed, it " Born: October 28, 1955 (age 64 years), Seattle...".

Comment: Aren't these two questions you recently posted extremely similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643795/for-loop-doesnt-work-for-web-scraping-google-search-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645955/for-loop-for-web-scraping-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
baseUrl = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
input_list = ["Bill Gates", "Elon Musk", "Warren Buffet"]
output = {}

def scrape_ceo_list(list_of_ceo):
     for ceo in list_of_ceo:
          browser.get(baseUrl + ceo)

          // query selectors, dataframes etc as per original code
          // ...

          output[ceo] = df
```

`output` is now a dictionary of data frames, with CEO names as dictionary keys.

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful, but it still didn't work though.

Comment: When you say it didn’t work - is it throwing an error (if so, what is it)? Or did it run and not generate the expected outcome?