# For loop doesn't work for web scraping Google search in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm working on web-scraping Google search with a list of keywords. The nested For loop for scraping a single page works well. However, the other for loop searching keywords in the list does not work as I intended to which **scrapes** the data for each searching result. The results didn't get the search outcome of the first two keywords, but it got only the result of the last keyword.

Here is the code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\...\chromedriver.exe")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ceo', 'value'])

baseUrl = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
ceo_list = ["Bill Gates", "Elon Musk", "Warren Buffet"]
values =[]
    

for ceo in ceo_list:
    browser.get(baseUrl + ceo)
    table = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.ifM9O') 

    for row in table:
        ceo = str(([c.text for c in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.kno-ecr-pt.PZPZlf.gsmt.i8lZMc')])).strip('[]').strip("''")
        value = str(([c.text for c in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.Z1hOCe')])).strip('[]').strip("''")

    ceo = pd.Series(ceo) 
    value = pd.Series(value)

    df = df.assign(**{'ceo': ceo, 'value': value}) 

       
print(df)

browser.close()
```

This is the output:

```
              ceo                                              value
0  Warren Buffett  Born: August 30, 1930 (age 89 years), Omaha, N...
```

What I'm expecting is this:

```
              ceo                                              value
0  Bill Gates      Born:..........
1  Elon Musk       Born:...........
2  Warren Buffett  Born: August 30, 1930 (age 89 years), Omaha, N...
```

Not sure which part was missing.

Comment: [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) overwrites existing columns.  You're probably looking for [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

Comment: Why the `str().strip('[]').strip("''")` ? That feels like such a hack. Is creating the `Series` even necessary? It's probably best to add the results to a temporary data structure, and then use that to create the DataFrame.

Comment: @ 0x5453 Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but it seems it is not the reason it doesn't work

Comment: Is this question drastically different from the other two similar ones you recently posted?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628327/google-search-web-scraping-with-a-list-of-key-words-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643795/for-loop-doesnt-work-for-web-scraping-google-search-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google search web scraping with a list of key words in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628327/google-search-web-scraping-with-a-list-of-key-words-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ceo as a list and append to it inside the for loop so you don't keep overwriting it