# For loop for web scraping in python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, loops, web-scraping

I have a small project working on web-scraping Google search with a list of keywords. I have built a nested For loop for scraping the search results. The problem is that a for loop for searching keywords in the list does not work as I intended to, which is scraping the data from each searching result. The results get only the result of the last keyword, except for the first two search results.

Here is the code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\...\chromedriver.exe")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ceo', 'value'])

baseUrl = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

ceo_list = ["Bill Gates", "Elon Musk", "Warren Buffet"]
values =[]


for ceo in ceo_list:
    browser.get(baseUrl + ceo)
    r = soup.select('div.g.rhsvw.kno-kp.mnr-c.g-blk')

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in r:

        value = i.select_one('div.Z1hOCe').text                     
        ceo = i.select_one('.kno-ecr-pt.PZPZlf.gsmt.i8lZMc').text   
        values = [ceo, value]

    s = pd.Series(values)
    df = df.append(s,ignore_index=True)


print(df)
```

The output:

```
              0                                                  1
0  Warren Buffet  Born: October 28, 1955 (age 64 years), Seattle...
```

The output that I am expecting is as this:

```
              0                                                  1
0  Bill Gates      Born:..........
1  Elon Musk       Born:...........
2  Warren Buffett  Born: August 30, 1930 (age 89 years), Omaha, N...


Any suggestions or comments are welcome here.
```

Comment: You are obtaining the last value of the loop. Try creating an empty array  and push the values when going through  the loop. Then the array will have all the values. Cheers.

Comment: It's almost always better to add your data to a temporary data structure and then create the DataFrame, rather than repeatedly appending or concatenating.

Comment: Also, is this different from the other two similar questions you recently posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628327/google-search-web-scraping-with-a-list-of-key-words-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643795/for-loop-doesnt-work-for-web-scraping-google-search-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google search web scraping with a list of key words in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628327/google-search-web-scraping-with-a-list-of-key-words-in-python)

Comment: @Jbae.H _I edited the others as you commented on the others but still can’t solve the issue._ What do you mean?

Comment: @AMC Yes, this one is the following question after I asked the other questions. I edited the others as you commented on the others but still can't solve the issue. Apologize if it causes any confusion or makes feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @Jbae.H My point is that they’re practically the same, no? It’s the same issue.

Comment: @AMC Yes, it is. And now I have more suggestions here from others to think of.

Comment: @Jbae.H Alright, but you can always edit the existing question, rather than reposting it multiple times.

Comment: @AMC Thank you. That's good to know. I am still learning about using stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `df = pd.DataFrame()` outside the for loop

Since currently, you have defined it inside the loop, for each keyword in your list it will initialize a new data frame and the older will be replaced. That's why you are just getting the result for the last keyword.

Try this:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\...\chromedriver.exe")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ceo', 'value'])
baseUrl = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
ceo_list = ["Bill Gates", "Elon Musk", "Warren Buffet"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for ceo in ceo_list:
    browser.get(baseUrl + ceo)
    r = soup.select('div.g.rhsvw.kno-kp.mnr-c.g-blk')
    for i in r:
        value = i.select_one('div.Z1hOCe').text                     
        ceo = i.select_one('.kno-ecr-pt.PZPZlf.gsmt.i8lZMc').text
    s = pd.Series([ceo, value])
    df = df.append(s,ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that part. One interesting thing is that the 'value' column only has the result of the first loop even though the output on the 'ceo' shows as it should be. Can you see any reason for that in the code?